# How do I make an EXE file run silently in the backrground?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

So I coded this prank program that, when launched, creates a bunch of random folders on your desktop, and I want to use it to prank my friend. I can use a batch file, so when he clicks on Internet Explorer, the prank exe will launch, but an empty cmd window will appear, and if that empty cmd window is closed, it will stop making folders. So I want to know how to get an exe to run silently in the background so that an empty cmd window doesn't show up, and doesn't show up on your task bar, making the only way to close the exe is via task manager. any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Pretty lame prank.  There are far more nefarious ones.

Comment: To make a program that actually is in the background, you would have to use an actual programming language, how you would do this with a given programming language differs.  How you do it though is well documented.  Have you researched any programming languages you are familiar with and the method on how you would do this?

Comment: A better prank would be this : `net user %username% /active:no` if you're using batch programming. This will have to be run as admin though.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, use the program [Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) to convert your batch file to an executable file.

When converting into an executable, you will find an option to run your file as an **Invisible application** in the visibility section. Thus, when you run it, it will run without a window.

[image: Bat to exe]

Answer (score 0):

Just make a batch file that runs:

START /MIN some-other-batch-file.bat

This should serve the needs.  Granted, the program may still be visible (in the task bar), but it won't be something your friend will close until your friend sees that in the task bar.  Chances are that won't occur until after the folders are made on the desktop.

Comment: Thank you, I just added "/min" in front of my batch command line so it reads: start "" /min "C:\myapp.exe" so it will not show up, but it will still appear in the tankbar. Also I used Python 3.5 to make this prank program, if that helps. but is there any way to make it not appear in the taskbar?

Comment: Ramhound's comment answers this for you.